# IE8 Array Ordering Bug

Tags: arrays, gwt, internet-explorer-8

Adding an element to an `ArrayList<String>` which has been constructed in 2 steps results in an out-of-sync array. It only happens in generated JS code, not in Development mode.

```
// The list where the bug occurs
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// Add a first element to the List
list.add("0");

//tmpList with elements that we will add at the end of the original 
//list(at least 32 elements makes the bug occurs) 

ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=1;i<33;i++) tmpList.add(""+i);
list.addAll(tmpList);

// The bug occurs when we add an element X to the position
// 1 or 2. The bug also occurs when usind addAll method
list.add(1,"X");
```

The resulting array is...

```
0 X 1 2 *4* *3* *4* 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

instead of the expected result...

```
0 X 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
```

This is a Workaround that works.

```
ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<1;i++)
   finalList.add(list.get(i));
finalList.add("X");
for(int i=1; i<list.size();i++)
   finalList.add(list.get(i));
```

Comment: Does this also occur if you add the "X" element prior to adding the other 32 items?

Comment: are you sure you are missing something? did you try it on another browser?

Comment: no, it does not occur prior to adding the other. and yes, we tried in other browsers. it only happens on ie7 & ie8. not tested on ie6. it works on firefox and chrome and ie9.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as correct. If not, please write the answer and mark your answer. This way you help others find an answer quick and you obide with the rules of the StackOverflow community

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a javascript bug with IE, try to add each element alone instead of using the **addAll** and see what's happening by debuggin the code :

```
for(int i=1;i<33;i++) list.add(i+"");
```